# Take dataframe with column that has values from 0 to 360 and wrap around to -180 to 180

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `'lon'` that has values which range from 0 - 15 and 250 - 360. I would like to wrap the values around from -180 to 180 without a for loop. So, the input is this:

```
df['lon'] = [1,10,15,250,360]
```

and the output should look like this

```
df['new_lon'] = [1,10,15,-110,0]
```

This would be easy to do with a for loop, but I would like to do it without a loop. In particular, I don't how to deal with dataframe where I want the values less than 15 to stay the same but I want the values greater than 15 to be changed.

Comment: `df.lon.loc[df.lon > 15] -= 180`

Comment: no, 360 would result in 180 then.

Comment: Use minmax scaler. Regards.

Comment: @Vovin better syntax would be `df.loc[df.lon > 15, 'lon'] -= 180`, try to avoid chained indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you can add 180, get the modulo 360, subtract 180:

```
df['lon'].add(180).mod(360).sub(180)
```

Other approach:

```
df['lon'].mask(df['lon'].gt(180), df['lon'].sub(360))
```

In place modification:

```
df.loc[df['lon'].gt(180), 'lon'] -= 360
```

output:

```
0      1
1     10
2     15
3   -110
4      0
Name: lon, dtype: int64
```